# gsoap doesn't work on Windows 10

Tags: c++, web-services, soap, windows-10, gsoap

I got the calc sample from gsoap web site and compile it under windows7. It worked perfectly. (VS 2013)
I done the same on windows 10 (VS 2015). It doesn't work. The server is still waiting. Th cleint time out after a few seconds with this msg:
*

> SOAP 1.1 fault SOAP-ENV:Server[no subcode] "A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond. " Detail: connect failed in tcp_connect()

*

I desactivated the firewall, tried to see what happens with wireshark but i didn't see anythink.

Any idea ?

Thanks for all.

Comment: What TCP port are you try to bind?

Comment: Hi, the port is default : 8080

Comment: Open cmd and type netstat -a verify if the process is binding to 8080 TCP port.